# How to integrate, run or combine a Flash game with my Titanium Appcelerator app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, titanium, appcelerator

I have developed three different games in Flash (Action Script 3) and they run well on my smartphone when I export them via Adobe Air.
I am creating an app over Titanium, and I intend to integrate these three games inside my main Titanium app. The problem is that Adobe Air only exports APKs files.

So I would like to know if there is anyway of making the games run inside the main app, without the need of calling external apps on the market, for example.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be use modular architecture. Meaning, the Main App would act as a wrapper for the three games.

In other words, you can load external SWF files (the games) in your main app using the `SWFLoader` class. Here is some more info about this class and how to use it, as well as module-wrapper communication info:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html

Have great day.